# Java: Basic Movement AI not working

Tags: java, ai, movement

I am working on a basic AI system to get an entity to follow a player. I created both the `player` and the `ghost` entity, but it seems as if the ghost only wants to increment both `x` and `y`, it never wants to do the opposite, or choose only `x` or `y` to use. Here is where I implemented the `ghost` and `player` in my constructor:

```
public MansionAzazel() {
    ...
    TileCoordinate ghostSpawn = new TileCoordinate(52, 50);
    TileCoordinate playerSpawn = new TileCoordinate(54, 52);
    player = new Player(playerSpawn.x(), playerSpawn.y(), key);
    player.init(level);
    ghost = new Ghost(ghostSpawn.x(), ghostSpawn.y(), player);
    ghost.init(level);
    ...
}
```

Here is the update() function for the ghost:

```
public void update() {
    int xa = 0, ya = 0;
    if (anim < 1000000)
        anim++;
    else
        anim = 0;

    if (player.getX() > xa)
        xa++;
    if (player.getX() < xa)
        xa--;
    if (player.getY() > ya)
        ya++;
    if (player.getY() < ya)
        ya--;

    if (xa != 0 || ya != 0) {
        move(xa, ya);
        walking = true;
    } else
        walking = false;
}
```

In which to sum it all up, the `ghost` entity will only and always move in one direction because the coordinates are 0 and I don't know why.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It looks like your ghost update function uses player.getX() when checking for Y coordinates. You might want to fix that. Also, you should output what player.getX() and player.getY() returns in your ghost update function to see what you get.

Comment: @UnderscoreZero I said that it returns -1 for both of them. I

Comment: What I meant was change the line `System.out.println(xa + ", " + ya);` to  `System.out.println(xa + ", " + ya + " " + player.getX() + ", " + player.getY());`

Comment: @UnderscoreZero after I changed getX to getY from checking y coordinate they both print out positive `1`

Also, I divided the `player.getX()` and `player.getY()` by 16 (tile size) it prints out the actual location, just not ghost.

Comment: You're missing your move function in the ghost update. Otherwise, yeah it's always going to give you the same stuff.

Comment: I updated the post with my current problem I am now facing, @UnderscoreZero

Comment: Keep putting in more debug prints. Half the fun of programming is debugging your code. Also, step through your code during run time and see if the program follows the paths you expect it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the intent is the move the ghost toward the player and if the move() method moves the ghost (you haven't given us enough info to be sure), then perhaps the update() method should initialize xa and ya to ghost.getX() and ghost.getY(). It seems to reset xa and ya to 0 every time update() is called.

Comment: Based on how his player uses the move() function, that is most likely not going to do what you expect it to do. I am assuming his move function takes the current position and offsets it by xa and ya. This same update function was used for his player and it worked fine.

Comment: Okay, @JMB you were quite right about that. It does reset the variables each time. Instead of using the my variables `xa` and `ya` I used `this.getX()` and `this.getY()` which worked perfectly!